# Including a JSP Page Programmatically

Tags: java, jsp

I need to include a JSP page in a `Tag` class. I believe the standard way to include a JSP page within another JSP page using API is this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("included.jsp").include(request, response);
```

However, I noticed that the included page is rendered at the top of the generated page, no matter where the code is located. This is true whether the code is placed in a `Tag` class or directly in the JSP file as scriptlet. On the other hand, the `<jsp:include>` action works as expected, rendering the included page where the tag appears in the JSP file.

How do I include a JSP page in a class so that it behaves the same as the `<jsp:include>`? There's no way to invoke the `<jsp:include>` action within a Tag class, is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your tag class should call `pageContext.getOut().flush();` prior to calling `request.getRequestDispatcher("included.jsp").include(request, response);`

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be lazy, but why not just look at a JSP compiled file. for example, tomcat compiles these to \work, and you can VIEW the java it produced there.